# How to use list with for loops in go

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, go, slice

I want to append numbers to a list but my slice update the value only in the for loop.

How do I update it outside?

```golang
slice := []int{5,4,3,2,1}

for i := 0; i < len(slice); i++ {
    slice := append(slice, i)
    fmt.Println(slice)
}

fmt.Println(slice)
```

Actual result

```golang
[5 4 3 2 1 0]
[5 4 3 2 1 1]
[5 4 3 2 1 2]
[5 4 3 2 1 3]
[5 4 3 2 1 4]
[5 4 3 2 1]
```

Expected result

```golang
[5 4 3 2 1 0]
[5 4 3 2 1 1]
[5 4 3 2 1 2]
[5 4 3 2 1 3]
[5 4 3 2 1 4]
[5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4]
```

This code works in Python but in go there is something I don't catch

Comment: the `slice` inside the loop is **block** scoped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't store the result of `append()` in your "original" `slice`, because you use [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) instead of [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments):

```
slice := append(slice, i)
```

The short variable declaration (since it's in a different block than the original `slice` variable) **creates a new variable** (shadowing the outer `slice`), and inside the loop you print this new variable. So the result of each append is only visible inside the loop body, and is lost when the iteration ends. Instead use assignment:

```
slice = append(slice, i)
```

However, when you do this, you'll get an infinite loop, because your loop condition is `i < len(slice)`, and `slice` grows in every iteration.

Instead you should do something like this (evaluate `len(slice)` once and store it):

```
for i, length := 0, len(slice); i < length; i++ {
    slice = append(slice, i)
    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

And output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hlXa-sJUya-)):

```
[5 4 3 2 1 0]
[5 4 3 2 1 0 1]
[5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2]
[5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3]
[5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4]
[5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4]
```

Note that you would get the same result if you'd use `for range`, because that only evaluates the slice once:

```
for i := range slice {
    slice = append(slice, i)
    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-oSCsqBComq).